# Elasticsearch dsl what does q('match', path = ) do?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

In python using elasticsearch_dsl.query there is a helper function Q that does the DSL query. However, i do not understand what this query is trying to say in a code i found:

```
ES_dsl.Q('match', path=path_to_file)
```

What exactly is `Q('match', path = path_to_file)` doing?

Where `path_to_file` is a valid path to a file in the system in the index.

Isn't path only in nested queries? There is no path in 'match' queries? I'm guessing it is to detokenize the path_to_file to find an exact match? An explanation to what is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the approach it takes is the query type as the first value, then what you want to query next. so that is saying;

1. run a match query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/query-dsl-match-query.html
2. use the `path` field and search for the value `path_to_file`

so matching that back to the docs page from above, it'd look like this in direct DSL;

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "path": {
        "query": "path_to_file"
      }
    }
  }
}
```